# How many ordered triples $(x,y,z)$ of positive integers satisfy $xyz=4000$

Tags: problem-solving

How would I find this out? Is there an equation or summation?

Comment: Do you know what the fundamental theorem of arithmetic is?

Answer (score 3):

Try decomposing 4000 into its prime factors and looking at what combinations you can have when splitting them into three groups.